# Capistrano Set Environment Variables

Tags: ubuntu, laravel, capistrano, capistrano3

Is there a way to set the environment variables on an Ubuntu box with a Capistrano deploy? I have a file with all the environment variables that need to be set. Right now when I deploy or those change I manually ssh into the box and set them but was wondering if I could automate this process?

Comment: I have Capistrano deployment working. Rocketeer is not a better solution just a different one. I prefer the Capistrano to deploy, so I don't see how deployment is offtopic? Thanks for your quick response though!

Comment: I think it's offtopic because it didn't attempt to answer your question. I didn't want to say that Rocketeer is a better solution, it's just as good as Capistrano. But I'm a PHP developer and I find it way easier to work with a PHP based solution with the same functionality than having to mess around with Ruby stuff instead :) And **concerning your question**: In Rocketeer there are callbacks for before/after deyploy/update where you can run CLI commands. I'm pretty sure that's also possible in Capistrano.

Comment: Do the environment variables need to persist across commands or are they just for one command?